# AC parallel and series circuit

Tags: voltage, current, ac, ohms-law

I have this AC circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDxdz2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have found VA which is \$222 \angle-119 mV\$.

The current flowing through the inductor \$IL = 2.6 \angle-89 mA\$

When I use Ohm's law to find current IR1 and IC2 they give me \$IR1=VA/R1 = 2.2 \angle-129 mA\$ and \$IC2=VA/XC2 = 1.3 \angle-39 mA\$  but when I add them (by converting them to rectangular form) they don't give me IL and I am confused why this is happening.

Comment: IR1+IC2 equals 2.55exp(-98i), which is not exactly your result for IL, but it is quite close, so I guess it is just an error from rounding.

Comment: What does 222<-119 mean?  Since you have a sinusoidal source all average currents and voltages must be zero.

Comment: This is clearly not the average voltages and currents.

Comment: \$V_A\$ is more like 231 mV at 2 kHz.